# jQuery - Multiple Overlapping Droppables Result in Unpredicable Drops

Tags: jquery-ui, droppable

I have a draggable that is being dropped on an isometric grid of droppables that overlap. The droppables are the grey tiles, img tags, and look like the first image attached. They are set to highlight blue when a draggable is over them.

Here is the source code for the droppable:

```
        $(".sprite").droppable({
            drop: function(event,ui) {
                object_id = ui.draggable.attr("id").replace("sprite_","");
                set_action('move_object',$(this).attr("id"));
                set_target(object_id);
                ui.draggable.removeClass("holding");
            },
            over: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace('.png','-hover-blue.png'));
            },
            out: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace('-hover-blue.png','.png'));
            },
            tolerance: 'pointer'
        });
```

Basically I'd like to have a) one tile highlight at a time, and b) have the highlighted tile be the one the object is dropped on.

I've tried every type of tolerance to no avail.

Images:

i.imgur.com/dGx9X.png

and

i.imgur.com/vb1d9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the drabbable move over a droppable you should deactivate all the other droppables and activate the current droppable.  Then it's simple to have the drop effect the active droppable.

in the over function

```
$(".sprite").not($(this)).removeClass("over")
   .each(function(){
     $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace('-hover-blue.png','.png'));
   });
$(this).addClass("over");
```

then in drop replace $(this) with $(".over")